# Words and reading level

Tags: readability

There are various measure for Reading Level.
Is there a source of information and scores/ratings for individual words? (I'm wondering if some words are only used by certain ages and/or education levels.)

If there is, can anyone point to some sources please?

If there is not, what would be a good (robust/mostly consistent) way to generate such scores?
Would frequency be good (though I think the texts used to get the frequencies may bias things and result in omissions?). Are syllable counts a viable method? How about looking at the "parts" (phonemes?) of the word, and looking at how common/uncommon they are compared to other words/constituent parts? (Ideally I'd like something that can be applied to any/all words ... so I think frequency may be a problem - unless someone knows a very large frequency resource?)

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid that measures for "Reading Level" are largely useless for any linguistic purpose. So if you need scores, go ahead and generate them any way you like, for any purpse you like. It's what everybody else does.

Comment: "Reading level" is about the only term I could think of that makes sense.  Basically, I'm looking for a way to rate words on their commonality and likelihood of usage based on education level/age.  I doubt many people use the word "indubitably", but of those that do, most will be over 10yrs of age, and likely more educated than not.  I'm hoping to find some sort of classification in that sense?

Comment: Education is not the same everywhere, and "level" is simply bureaucratic arbitrariness. For starts, are you talking about language (i.e, speech), or writing (i.e, technology)? Are you talking about English or some other language? Are you talking about recognition, recall, or use of words? About correct or incorrect use? About successful or unsuccessful learners (and how do you decide)?

Comment: Hmmm.  In order : No, it's not // All ratings are somewhat false/arbitary (barring extremes) // Written word // English (GB+US(+CLNL?)) // Mainstream/general usage (so likely Usage, then Recog., and poss. Recall as a decider?) // Correct usage would be preferred.  Successful/Unsuccessful learners is moot - either they are in a group that should recognise/use a word, or are not. //// I know that the reading score systems are somewhat arbitrary and generally have flaws to varying degrees - but is there nothing similar for "words" rather than sentences/phrases/paragraphs etc.?

Comment: Written English words are like telephone numbers or any other random sequence of symbols. Different people learn them at different rates at different times for different reasons, and there is no reason to believe any differential has to do with the words instead of the learners.

Comment: Yes/No.  Though I agree (largely), the education system (where-ever/what-ever) generally (attempts?) to teach specific word sets.  Thus "most" 10 year olds (in the same system) should know (roughly) the same words (or at least been exposed to them).  I would assume that these words are selected under certain criteria and/or for specific reasons (I doubt anyone attempts to teach 4 year olds the same words as those taught at uni. level).  So though arbitrary and over generalised, there IS a systematic approach, and a collective yield.

Comment: Push comes to shove, I'll just have to scrape a bunch of word-lists out of various syllabi for various age-ranges, and try to find some sort of common theme per group.  Hopefully there will be some sort of quantitative measure, rather than qualitative that I can utilise.

Comment: Source 1: There is a number of OECD studies such as PISA that measured reading proficiency internationally. Source 2: Speech/language therapists need to test speakers in order to see whether they need therapy. They have developed a variety of test batteries, and there should also be some for reading (although that is not the major focus in speech therapy).

Comment: @robert - Thank you very much!  I'll look into the OECD/PISA and let you know how it goes.